# wkhtmltopdf dynamic margins

Tags: php, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Is it possible, using wkhtmltopdf, to define dynamic margins ?

I'm generating a pdf for an invoice, on the first page I have the BVR in the footer so the user can cut it out and pay with it. On pages besides the first one, I have no footer.

The problem is that, when having enough content to fill the second page fully, the page breaks occurs at the given footer margin, leaving me with a page empty for 1/3.

Is it possible to define (javascript or other ways) a dynamic margin size for the first page, and then remove the bottom margin for any other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You can create a feature request at https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues, but I don't think this is coming any time soon because the underlying technology (webkit) has stabilised (doesn't change often) and doesn't really need this feature.

How about for a workaround you examine the content and if it's the specific length you split the HTML to two files and convert them individually. Then you can join them with pdftk for example.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll take a look to pdftk to see what I can do

Comment: It works indeed, but I have a problem with page numbers, is there a possibility or workaround to get consecutives page numbers ? ex: pdf1: 1 page, pdf2, 2pages, now I get "page 1, page 1, page 2", is it possible to get 1,2,3 instead ?

Comment: Yeah, by using the `--page-offset <number>` parameter for the second conversion :)

Comment: awesome ! :) now I just have to find the number of pages of previous pdf (fastest way possible as I'm doing a batch conversion of 1000+ pdf)